# Is [socket.io] [sockets]?

Tags: discussion, tags

[sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sockets) are an API your operating system provides for network communication.

[socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/socket.io) is also a library for network communication, but it acts more like HTTP and tries to hide the underlying implementation from you. It may use plain old sockets, but you couldn't tell. It also introduces a bunch of abstraction on top, like a system of rooms, where connections can be added to rooms and then you can broadcast messages to specific rooms.

Many questions about socket.io get tagged with [sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sockets) because of course socket.io calls its things sockets. Example [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73154866/socket-io-client-makes-several-connections-instead-of-just-one) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73154065/socket-io-not-giving-the-same-id-in-client-and-in-server) [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73153519/socket-io-in-svelte-via-store) [four](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72534527/how-do-i-start-websocket-server-socketio-or-otherwise-in-nuxt-3-does-not-work/73069618) [five](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73053017/using-socket-io-with-redis-on-express-js-server-is-too-slow).

Is it appropriate to remove [sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sockets) from these questions?

Comment: @KevinB I think this is more like asking whether sockets should be tagged on HTTP questions. Many questions tagged [sockets]+[socket.io] have nothing to do with the way data is transported - they can be about the rooms API, for example.

Comment: That [second linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73154065/socket-io-not-giving-the-same-id-in-client-and-in-server) is clearly just a mistag anyways, since it's tagged [[tag:sockets]] [[tag:io]] lol

Comment: As with almost all questions of the "should I do [blanket action]?" sort, the answer is, "It depends". Were you actually expecting an answer that said something different?

Comment: Unix/linux sockets are the same as Microsoft's pipes and are network terminology with specific questions about networking what that questions have to do with a library is beyond me

Answer (score 8):

I'm gonna throw my hat in the "generally yes" camp, though we always need to handle each individual post according to its own merits when making edits.

[socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/socket.io) is an abstraction of "sockets" as a concept, and in practice is [a library built on top of WebSockets](https://socket.io/docs/v4/) to offer a more robust and feature-rich experience than WebSockets alone can offer.

[sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sockets), on the other hand, is more of a lower-level mechanism; [the tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sockets/info) describes them as "an endpoint of a bidirectional inter-process communication flow". This is distinct from protocols or abstractions, and the [sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sockets) wiki itself *explicitly asks* readers not to confuse them with such, even mentioning [socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/socket.io) by name:

> Not to be confused with [websocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/websocket) (a protocol) or other abstractions (e.g. [socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/socket.io)).

Given the above then, I don't see how a question asking about the [socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/socket.io) library could ever have much to do with [sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sockets), the flow endpoint mechanism. **This then means that the vast, vast majority of questions tagged with [socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/socket.io) should not be tagged with [sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sockets).**

(Glancing over [the library docs](https://socket.io/docs/v4/), I really don't see how traditional [sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sockets) could come into play for library users at all, since the library seems to intentionally abstract them away based on what I can tell.)

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't touch it.

Given that [the tag description for socket](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sockets/info) differs wildly from [the tag description for socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/socket.io/info), this leads me to believe that [socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/socket.io) is some kind of library or framework which also deals with [socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/socket)s.